# SSD read for a large file using c++

Tags: c++, file

I am working on a windows 10 64-bit machine, 6850K CPU, and 64 GB DDR4 RAM,  with a Samsung SSD connected via M.2. I want to read a file that is about 15 GB in size, to memory. I am currently using fstream to read the entire file in to an array of unsigned chars using a single call to its read function. However, the speeds I achieve are not hitting the maximum read speeds of the SSD (1500 MB/s when the SSD read is around 3500 MB/s).

So I was wondering if there was a faster way? Would it be faster if I made multiple read calls for smaller chunks? If so, what is the optimal chunk size? I have seen some people mention 4K reads in some previously asked questions. Does that apply in this case?

Any help is appreciated.

My code excerpt is as follows

my read code is as follows

```
fstream myFile;
myFile.open("file", ios::binary | ios::in);
myFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(buf), 14929920000LL);
```

where `buf` is the same size as the read.

Comment: You may be limited by bus speed. If the read speed is for SATA3, for instance, you may be running on SATA2. Have you checked this?

Comment: Also: please post the code you are using to do the read.

Comment: my read code is as follows

`fstream myFile;`
`myFile.open("file", ios::binary | ios::in);`
`myFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(buf), 14929920000LL);`

where buf is the same size as the read.

Comment: Have you tried using `mmap()`? It might go faster by avoiding unnecessary copying.

Comment: @Richard

I added the code. The SSD is connected to the M.2 slot. Running Crystal Mark does give ~3500 MB/s as the read speed. as well.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716826/what-is-the-purpose-of-hard-disk-direct-memory-access

Comment: @HellmarBecker

Thank you, I will try that. It is not something I am too familiar with, so was hoping to avoid it.

Comment: don't avoid things you aren't familiar with! how will you learn?

Comment: @CoryNelson True :) 
Was also wondering, looking at the mmap info on MSDN, it seems like the max size that can be mapped at a time is a DWORD sized chunk. Is there a way around that, or do I need to map the large file in small pieces?

Comment: To get the fastest read speed, you need to bypass the windows disk cache.  Use Windows API calls `CreateFile`, `ReadFile`, etc. and use unbuffered reads (pass `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` to `CreateFile`, and pay close attention to the required memory alignment necessities).  This will transfer data directly from the disk to the memory block you need without having to copy the data from one memory address to another.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm

Thank you so much for those suggestions, I will try them out as well. If I may ask, what is meant by memory alignment necessities? I am still new to programming, so sorry if this should be obvious.

Comment: There may be hardware imposed requirements for addresses, typically 512 byte aligned, but some newer hardware may want 4096 bytes.  Others may not be as strict.  A link in the [`CreateFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx) documentation give the full details for `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING`.

Comment: have you tried memory mapped IO?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Your solution worked!!! :) Thank you so much! Can you post your comment as an "Answer" so that I can choose it as the solution for my question? I really appreciate you helping me out with this problem, and would like it to be recognized!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the fastest read speed, you need to bypass the windows disk cache. Use Windows API calls `CreateFile`, `ReadFile`, etc. and use unbuffered reads (pass `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` to `CreateFile`). This will transfer data directly from the disk to the memory block you need without having to copy the data from one memory address to another.

You'll need to pay close attention to the required memory alignment necessities that may be imposed by hardware.  This typically requires memory addresses to be 512 byte aligned, but some newer hardware may want 4096 bytes, and others may not be as strict.  A link in the [CreateFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx) documentation gives the full details for `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING`.